# getting mobile_number undefined in Controller

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

```
                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="mobile_number"
                        render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
                            <TextInput
                                style={[styles.textInput]}
                                onBlur={onBlur}
                                onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
                                value={value}
                                keyboardType="phone-pad"
                                placeholder={content.placeholder.loginNumber}
                            />
                        )}
                        rules={{ required: true }}
                        defaultValue=""
                    />
```

**getting mobile_number undefined in Controller**

```
  {errors.mobile_number?.type === "required" && <AppText style=                                  {styles.inputError}>{content.inputError.numberRequired}</AppText>}
                    {errors.mobile_number?.type === "minLength" && <AppText style={styles.inputError}>{content.inputError.numberLength}</AppText>}
                    {errors.mobile_number?.type === "maxLength" && <AppText style={styles.inputError}>{content.inputError.numberLength}</AppText>}
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile_number' of undefined